# Appropriate visa required by a visiting research PhD student

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I am currently both a medicine resident and a PhD student at an EU-university.

I want to come to the UK for a 1-year period to perform research activity (which would be consistent with my PhD, although obviously carried out with a supervisor in the UK institution). I will not perform any clinical activity, nor enrolling in any course in the UK institution.

I am struggling to understand what kind of Visa do I need to do this kind of activity.
Some say is the Tier 5 visa under one of the GAE scheme (although I do not recognize any of the scheme as appropriate, maybe the "sponsored research"? But I cannot understand if I meet the requirements); some other say that a Tier 4 (Student Visa) would be appropriate.

Comment: Can the international office of your UK host institution advise on your situation?

Comment: @B.Liu yes, but I just want to figure out others' experience

Comment: Eligibility for a Student visa depends on the course the applicant is planning to do https://www.gov.uk/student-visa/course. Otherwise the GAE route you mention seems to be the best option https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-government-authorised-exchange-schemes

Comment: @Traveller the only doubt here is whether a PhD student can fit the "Sponsored Researcher" programme... what do you think?

Comment: That will depend on whether the institution has the relevant sponsor licence and offers you sponsorship https://www.gov.uk/uk-visa-sponsorship-employers